How do I fix Material Shrinking

To be clear, I am NOT using a texture; this is done using the material editor. I don't know how to fix this; moving the UV around does not do anything.

Hello please show a screenshot of the shader editor or even share your object: blend-exchange.com

Well, you are using a texture, and you need a "texture coordinates" node to drive the input of your texture, noise, whatever. Ideally you should create the UVs and take the UV from the "texture coordinate" node

As Daniel says, if you are not using the Texture Coordinate node before a procedural texture node, by default the texture will be projected with the Generated mode, which means that the object proportion will be taken into account, example with the Checker Texture on a flat cube (make sure that you've applied the scale of the object by the way):

To fix the problem, create a Texture Coordinate and a Mapping node before the Texture node, then use the Generated output and change the Scale Z value of the Mapping to correct the stretching, or use the Object output and change all the Z values of the Mapping to correct the whole texture proportion:

